# how to make mini buffer "sticky"?

Tags: minibuffer, info

So I wanted to make mini buffer "sticky."

Currently, I am using doom emacs. When I look up info page using `spc h i` for example, mini buffer popups from below. The problem with this mini buffer is that if I mistype q, esc or C-q, it will quit. Also, sometimes, when I want to read up or make notes on a info manual, the mini buffer is too small. I know hwo to change the size of it, but I only want mini buffer to enlarge on info manual only.

So what I think I could do is somehow "convert mini buffer into buffer." This seems to be possible, but I am not sure how to approach this even better if there is a command for this already.

When I open mini buffer and proceed to "convert it to buffer," what I think I can do is.

1. somehow store a command that open this page in mini buffer. (e.g. link to info, command to open up describe page.)
2. close mini buffer
3. select a buffer to run the stored command.

It seems like there should be better ways.

Comment: FWIW, your question is completely unclear to me. But you seem to have gotten a relevant answer (which you can accept, BTW).

Comment: The "minibuffer" in Emacs is the buffer at the very bottom of the frame where you interactively respond to prompts such as when using `M-x` or entering a filename to visit, or answering a yes/no question.  I don't use Doom, but displaying an info page seems *highly* unlikely to use the minibuffer, so perhaps you could edit your question text to not use the phrase "mini buffer" if that is not what you mean, as it makes the question confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how doom manage mini buffer. You can take a look at [popper](https://github.com/karthink/popper) which have the function `popper-toggle-type` that `Turn a popup buffer BUFFER into a regular window or vice-versa.` .

For the info page You can use org-store-link and org-insert-link to save info link.

Comment: That's what I want thank you. How to you find this information? I get a feeling that it is not something you are familiar with beforehand.

Comment: For most questions, if they are not familiar to me, I will write down my attempts to find the answer. But this answer happens to be something I'm using.